# Trouble adding toFixed(3) to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a simple px to em converter. I've got it working but am having trouble restricting the results to three decimal places. I'm trying to use the toFixed(3) method but whenever I include it, the variable stops being added to the html.

Heres a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nowlesy/usr5c0ac/

Heres the html

## PX to EM converter

```
<div id="base">
<h2>Enter a base pixel size</h2>
<input id="baseSize" value="126" maxlength="4"><p>px</p>
</div>

<div id="px">
<input id="pxInput" value="16" maxlength="4"><p>px</p>
<div id="emOutput2"></div>
</div><p>em</p>

<div id="Em">
<input id="emInput" value="1" maxlength="4"><p>em</p>
<div id="pxOutput2">
</div><p>px</p></div>
```

And the js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#pxInput").keyup(function(){
     var emOutput = function (){ return $('#pxInput').val()/$('#baseSize').val();};
     $('#emOutput2').html(emOutput);
});
$("#emInput").keyup(function(){
     var pxOutput = function (){ return $('#emInput').val()/$('#baseSize').val();};
     $('#pxOutput2').html(pxOutput);
});


$("#baseSize").keyup(function(){
     var pxOutput = function (){ return $('#emInput').val()/$('#baseSize').val();};
     $('#pxOutput2').html(pxOutput);


     var emOutput = function (){ return $('#pxInput').val()/$('#baseSize').val();};
     $('#emOutput2').html(emOutput);
});

 var baseSize2= $('#baseSize').val();
 var pxInput = $('#pxInput').val();
 var emInput =$('#emInput').val();
 var emOutput = function (){ return pxInput/baseSize2;};
 var pxOutput = function (){return emInput*baseSize2;};

 ('#baseSize').attr('value', baseSize2);
 $('#pxInput').attr('value', pxInput);
 $('#emInput').attr('value', emInput);
 $('#pxOutput2').html(pxOutput);
 $('#emOutput2').html(emOutput);

 });
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: But there are no calls to `.toFixed()` in your code ???

Comment: It is because .val() returns a string type and you can apply tofixed to numbers. So use parseInt(value).toFixed(3) and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have `pxOutput` as a function who returns a value.  jQuery can deal with this but calling `.toFixed()` on a function won't work.  Personally I would replace the whole approach with something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/usr5c0ac/1/)):

```
var pxOutput = (parseInt($('#emInput').val(), 10)/parseInt($('#baseSize').val(), 10)).toFixed(3);
```

You can also begin to generalize this into a function like this:

```
function convert(input) {
    return (parseInt(input.val(), 10) / parseInt($('#baseSize').val(), 10)).toFixed(3);
};
```